# rosdep 2 install system dependencies

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
it seems like i do not totally understand rosdep2. I could easily add my own system dependencies in rosdep. in the sources.list file I tried to add local yaml file addresses as:

yaml /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/opencv.yaml

in order to use my own built opencv-svn (Opencv2.4) package, but it rejects it because:

url must be a fully-specified URL with scheme, hostname, and path

How can I add system dependencies to rosdep2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33550/rosdep-2-install-system-dependencies/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the document on [defining rosdep rules](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) .

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-17**:
You probably need to add something like file:// at the beginning.